# The Ruby gets method truncates my input at 256 characters

Tags: ruby, windows, string, gets

I am trying to enter a long string (> 256 characters but generally < 512) in Ruby with:

```
puts "Enter long string"
ilogo = gets.chomp
puts "#{ilogo}"
```

For some silly reason, it always truncates the input to keep only 256 characters (before chomp).
I verified that Ruby accepts longer strings, and that Windows 7 command line console also accepts strings > 256 chars.
I can't find any mention of the gets method having that type of limitation, but I am surely missing something.  I am clueless.  Could that be just a gets limitation?

Edit: Just to be more specific: one of the test strings I am using is:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111123456777777777777777777777
```

Where 6 corresponds to the 256th character.
As indicated, the string truncates all characters beyond the 256th.

Comment: where are you trying to print this to?

Comment: Just tested this, works fine here on ruby 1.9.3p392 on Mac OS X 10.8. Also, did you mean `ilogo` instead of `"ilogo"` for the variable?

Comment: It's not a general `gets` limitation - I just confirmed otherwise with IRB on MacOS.

Comment: why you used `puts "ilogo"` instead of `puts ilogo`?

Comment: Just tried this in IRB on Windows XP. Pasted in 500 characters with `gets`.... and it only took 254 of the chatacers. Huh. =\

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it, I meant puts "#{ilogo}"

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Just printing it to my windows 7 command line console.

Comment: Though it wouldn't be a fix but rather a work-around, you could save the string you want to input into a `txt` file and then read it in using `File`.

Comment: @Charles That would not be very practical, I just want to paste a long command.  I could also divide the input string in segments < 256.

Comment: The machine is 64 bits

Comment: I tried the same thing in Python on Windows XP and it took all 500 characters. Definitely some limitation in Ruby.

Comment: Anybody else can enter string > 256 characters with 'gets' on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to post this bug report is the mailing list Ruby-Talk,  http://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/ruby.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report, #8427.